# DataGrid ItemDataBound not binding as expected

Tags: asp.net

I am using ItemDataBound of DataGrid to perform the below tasks:

1. Check the Checked Value of a CheckBox Present in the row.
2. Based on the checked value set the Enabled Property of three textboxes in the same row.

Here is my code:

```js
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            CheckBox ck = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkStatus");
            bool isChecked = ck.Checked;
            TextBox txt1 = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt1"));
            TextBox txt2 = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt2"));
            TextBox txt3 = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt3"));
            txt1.Enabled = isChecked;
            txt2.Enabled = isChecked;
            txt3.Enabled = isChecked;
 }
```

When I put Break Point and inspect the values Enabled is getting Properly Set. For Example if the CheckBox is Checked all three textboxes.Enabled Property Set to true, else set to false. But once I press continue the row which has the CheckBox Checked will have all the three textboxes Enabled. But the rows where the checkbox is unchecked, there too the three textboxes are enabled rather than being disabled.

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Can anybody explain what is wrong in my code? I would like to know what happens when ItemDataBound Event has completed. Is there any other function is being called automatically which is messing with the values. I even tried by Enabling View State. But still no use.

I ma setting BackGround Color Property. It is fine. But Eanbled Property is not set to false.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This should not happen.Is there any JavaScript code interfering??

Comment: Try setting some other property of the textbox e.g text or background color just to ensure that you are getting handle of correct textboxes. Also, right click on one of the textboxes that should be disabled and inspect element (developer tools) to see if disabled attribute is applied

Comment: @GaganDeep No there is No JavaScript on this page.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I will try setting some other text box property on Monday as I have to be in office network to access DB. But as I said while debugging I see enabled property of all three textboxes being set to false. I also inspected the element but no disabled attribute was applied. I do have an event listener on the checkbox. When I check/uncheck the behaviour is correct. But not in ItemDataBound event.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I did change other properties of the textbox like background color/visible properties. It is being set. But only Enabled property is not being set. I have updated the question with another Image where background color property is set but Enabled Property is not set to false. Any idea why?

Comment: That’s weird. Try something like this txt1.Attributes[“disabled”]=“disabled” and check if it works

Comment: Hi  @MohsinMehmood this worked thanks 

Comment: Great! I have just posted the fix as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by explicitly setting the disabled attribute of text box like

```
txt1.Attributes[“disabled”]=“disabled”;
```